# Android: RoboTabActivity requestWindowFeature() hanging with no exception (RoboGuice 1.1)

Tags: android, android-activity, roboguice

```
boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

I'm calling this method within an initialization method of my RoboTabActivity (before setContentView), and it appears to hang on this line without throwing any exceptions. Any idea  what could be causing this strange behavior?

Using RoboGuice 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could have either been a problem because I didn't call it in onCreate(), or it was a threading issue. I'm now calling requestWindowFeature() immediately without waiting for any other tasks to complete first - no more issue.

I should also note that I changed the RoboTabActivity to just a TabActivity, this may have also been the culprit. Sorry I couldn't be more concise with my answer